# genmsg_cpp on Windows

Tags: ros, windows, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a transportation system simulator application, that uses roscpp on Windows. I'm trying to find a way to generate c++ header files from YAML srv/msg files. I found about the genmsg_cpp but can't find it now, the search on the wiki gives me this page http://www.ros.org/wiki/genmsg_cpp which lists the svn archive https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/trunk/core/genmsg_cpp , that does not exist anymore. I would greatly appreciate is somebody could explain how to generate the header files without using the build script, which is not available on Windows.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36377/genmsg_cpp-on-windows/) by [dunduk](https://answers.ros.org/users/2602/dunduk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're after just basic msg types, you can use the [Windows SDK](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20SDK%20-%20Fuerte). Otherwise, you can always add extra msg stacks and [build the sdk](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20Build%20Environment%20-%20Fuerte) with your extra msgs yourself. The sdk will give you roscpp, roscpp serialization and msgs.

If they are just standard ros messages which have already been catkinized, I can add them easily to the sdk build for you.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1